# Is there a way to cold boot AVD with custom files inside?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I want to run some tests that will require me to delete and create new AVDs, Android booting for the first time and having the apk there ready to install would save a lot of time, doing adb install and streaming the .apk's to the virtual device take a long time of the tests.

I'm wondering if there is a way to accomplish such thing, creating and running new AVDs with files ready to be used inside, maybe with virtual sdcard attached?

**I'm not using Android Studio, using cmdline-tools and emulator CLI.**

Answer (score 0):

Just create the emulator like you want, then copy the emulator file.  Now you have 2 emulators exactly the same

Comment: Not really what I'm seeking as the objective of running multiple devices are the difference between those.